# Mapstruct map nested from multiple source

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a `Y` inside `X` and a `ZDTO` inside `YDTO` but there is no `Z` inside `Y`.
I want to map `X` to `XDTO` with a method like `XDTO xToXDTO(X x, Z z)`

Given X,Y,Z as follows:

```
public class X {
    private Y y;
    private Integer xa;
    private Integer xb;
}
public class Y {
    private Integer ya;
    private Integer yb;
}
public class Z {
    private Integer za;
    private Integer zb;
}
```

And their `DTO`s as follows:

```
public class XDTO {
    private YDTO y;
    private Integer xa;
    private Integer xb;
}
public class YDTO {
    private ZDTO z;
    private Integer ya;
    private Integer yb;
}
public class ZDTO {
    private Integer za;
    private Integer zb;
}
```

I have this `Mapper` class:

```
@Mapper
public interface XYZMapper {

    XDTO xToXDTO(X x, Z z);
    YDTO yToYDTO(Y y, Z z);
    ZDTO zToZDTO(Z z);
}
```

I expect that the mapper calls `yToYDTO` for mapping `Y` to `YDTO`, but when I see the generated code I see it has created a `yToYDTO1` and is not using the `YDTO yToYDTO(Y y, Z z)`

This is the generated code by `MapStruct`

```
public XDTO xToXDTO(X x, Z z) {
    if ( x == null && z == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    XDTO xDTO = new XDTO();

    if ( x != null ) {
        xDTO.setY( yToYDTO1( x.getY() ) );
        xDTO.setXa( x.getXa() );
        xDTO.setXb( x.getXb() );
    }

    return xDTO;
}
```

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès it is in the generated MapStruct code